# templates C++ with GCC

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc

I'm trying to port C++ windows application to Linux. And i have promlems. I don't know how to explain it correctly, but i'll try.

I have next code:In header file:

```
    template<typename bidtype,typename chartype>
class pst_appointment_impl :
    virtual public pst_appointment,
    public pst_message_impl<bidtype,chartype>
{
...
}
```

In cpp file(and there are my problems):

```
...
template pst_appointment_impl<DWORD, char>;
template pst_appointment_impl<DWORDLONG,wchar_t>;
```

I don't know, how it calls exactly, but VS2010 compile it well. 
BUT, in linux, GCC gives errors "Syntax error" on this last two lines.

Any ideas how to fix this?

======================================================

**[EDITION]**

All windows types are defined.
I'm using Eclipse on linux. It gives errors "cannot resolve name", when there are problems with types, but now: "Syntax error"

Comment: First make sure that `DWORD` and `DWORDLONG` are defined (they wouldn't be by default, you would have to provide those definitions somewhere.)

Comment: You'd need to define DWORD and DWORDLONG so you could do `typedef unsigned int DWORD;` etc

Comment: DWORD, DWORDLONG and others are defined...

Comment: Can you post the complete and full error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `DWORD` and `DWORDLONG` correctly and use

```
template class pst_appointment_impl<DWORD, char>;
template class pst_appointment_impl<DWORDLONG, wchar_t>;
```

Comment: MSVC (may) produces warning when you mix `struct`/`class` between declarations/definition.

Comment: But that would be non-standard.